# Sum value and merge data when mapping data with duplicate product names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

We're mapping data in order to quickly save an API dump to the database.

However, some of the items are listed twice so how would we add their value to each other?

For example, we're getting positions has a ticker of "CASH" twice, and they have the values 20 and 30. We should like to only save "CASH" once with a value of 50.

```
 final_data = import_positions.map do |position|
  [
    portfolio_quovo_idnum(position.portfolio),
    position.id,
    get_asset(position),
    stock_ticker_symbol(position.ticker),
    position.cost_basis,
    position.cost_basis_type,
    position.fxrate,
    position.last_purchase_date,
    position.market_code,
    position.price * 100,
    position.quantity.to_d,
    position.sector,
    position.security_type,
    position.ticker_name,
    position.value * 100,
    get_portfolio_makeup(position),
    get_user_makeup(position)
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
value_sum = Hash.new(0)
import_positions.each do |position|
  value_sum[position.ticker_name] += position.value
end
```

This will give you a hash of the summed values. Then:

```
final_data = import_positions.uniq{|p| p.ticker_name}.map do |position|
  [
    portfolio_quovo_idnum(position.portfolio),
    position.id,
    ...
    position.ticker_name,
    value_sum[position.id] * 100,
    ...
  ]
end
```